# File system symbol on "+" (drwxr-x---+ 2 root root 4096 Jan 20 21:48 myusername)

Tags: files, filesystems, acl

What is the meaning of "+" in `ls`'s output? There is a symbol behind `drwxr-x---`. The "+" is a new sign to me. I heard ACL (Access Control list). Does anyone know more about this? I saw it on my mount device (`/media`).

```
drwxr-x---+  2 root     root     4096 Jan 20 21:48
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's system-dependent. On most Linux systems, GNU `ls` [uses `+` to indicate "alternate access methods" other than security contexts (SELinux)](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed):

> GNU `ls` uses a ‘`.`’ character to indicate a file with a security context, but no other alternate access method.
>
> A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is marked with a ‘`+`’ character.

Typically it does indicate the presence of ACLs; you can see these with

```
getfacl /media
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do I get this? I have no cues. This is to indicate to my account. I have a external device(HDD) and mount on /media which I divide the partitions for my external device.

Comment: I know what it is. Anyway, I use setfacl to dismiss + on my directory.